# Basis functions for a finite interval zero at ends

Tags: functional-analysis, change-of-basis

Is there a standard set of 1-dimensional basis functions $B_i(x)$ for a finite interval [0, 1], which span the set of all continuous differentiable functions
$$f(x) = \sum_i B_i(x)$$
and which are zero at both ends, namely $B_i(0) = B_i(1) = 0 \;\; \forall i$ ?

Comment: Most likely you want $B_i(x)=\sin(i \pi x)$. There are other choices out there, though, it depends what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Ian I'm sorry, of course! I for whatever reason thought that $\sin(i\pi x)$ is always symmetric, but only every second basis function is symmetric.